# Vim how to run/load certain plugins on certain filetypes?

Tags: c++, vim, plugins, file-type

I was wondering if it's possible to only run/load certain plugins for certain filetypes? For example, I have YouCompleteMe and Syntastic installed via Vundle, but I only want to load them when I'm actually editing a C++ file.

It doesn't just limit it to just those plugins, it could be basically anything. The reason for this is because I want to minimize the amount of plugins loaded for other files, otherwise it'll be loaded for a file say, .txt even though there's really no point in doing so (which also means that things will be faster :) )

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is trivial with NeoBundle. Here is an example from `:help :NeoBundleLazy`:

```
NeoBundleLazy 'Rip-Rip/clang_complete'
autocmd FileType c,cpp NeoBundleSource clang_complete
```

You can very easily convert your Vundle setup to NeoBundle, seeing how the latter is a fork of the former.